# Blender python script for a primitive blender exporter

Tags: python, blender

I am trying to write a very basic export to blender (from primitive shapes) script. I have to draw cylinders, at various angles and positions. I have information of offset position, and dimensions.

```
import bpy
import bgl
from mathutils import *
from math import *

material = bpy.data.materials.new('red')
material.diffuse_color = (1.0,0.0,0.0)


def draw_cylinder(name,material,radius,depth,location,rotation,offsetPosition,offsetAngle):

    bgl.glRotatef(*offsetAngle[:4]) 
    bgl.glTranslatef(*offsetPosition[:3])

    bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_cylinder_add(radius=radius, depth=depth, location=location, rotation=rotation)

    Cylinder = bpy.context.active_object
    Cylinder.name = name
    Cylinder.active_material = material

    bgl.glTranslatef(*[i*-1 for i in offsetPosition[:3]])
    bgl.glRotatef(*[i*-1 for i in offsetAngle[:4]])

    return Cylinder

cmpt = draw_cylinder('first',material,radius=1,depth=2,location=(-1,0,0),rotation=(pi/2,0,0),offsetPosition=(10,2,7),offsetAngle=(pi/2,0,1,0))
```

This does not draw the cylinder at (9,2,7) [nor rotated along y axis] where am i terribly wrong? How can i correct this. Much Appreciate your help.

EDIT: Using Blender version 2.60 (python interactive console 3.2.2)
Output shows the cylinder, at (-1,0,0). I expect/need it to be at (9,2,7) (location+offsetPosition)

Comment: Please state Blender version, as after 2.49 blender uses Python 3 with a different API

Comment: added the asked details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the function `draw_cylinder`, you need to add the two vectors:

```
pos = (
    location[0]+offsetPosition[0],
    location[1]+offsetPosition[2],
    location[1]+offsetPosition[2],
)
```

and then

```
bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_cylinder_add(radius=radius, depth=depth, location=pos, rotation=rotation)
```

**[EDIT]** If you need more complex operations, have a look at the [mathutils library](http://www.blender.org/documentation/blender_python_api_2_56_0/mathutils.html).

Comment: What about the rotation matrix? There is an offset rotation with the original location.

Comment: In that case, have a look at the `mathutils` library which contains all kinds of operations: http://www.blender.org/documentation/blender_python_api_2_56_0/mathutils.html